# Использование инициализированного в antrun параметра в плагине дочернего модуля

Tags: java, maven

Мне нужно инициализировать параметр в родительском проекте и использовать его значение в конфигурации плагина в дочернем модуле.Для наглядности в примере настраивается id плагина, в реальном случае нужно настраивать phase.Возможно ли это сделать "в лоб"?

Полный код - https://github.com/chemist22888/example

antrun плагин парента:

```xml
<plugin>
    <!-- Workaround maven not being able to set a property conditionally based on environment variable -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                <target>
                    <property name="test.id" value="testId"/>
                    <property name="test.phase" value="generate-sources"/>

                    <echo message="parent phase ${test.id}"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

чайлда:

```xml
<plugin>
    <!-- Workaround maven not being able to set a property conditionally based on environment variable -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>${test.phase}</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <echo message="child ${test.phase}"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

После запуска в чайлде корректно выводится параметр, но id плагина - `${test.phase}`, вместо ожидаемого `generate-sources`